# Display loading icon when transitioning between divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have a form, that when the "Next" button is clicked, a new div appears in place of the old one with this code:

```js
function showDiv() {
                   
                    
                    
                    document.getElementById('2').style.display="block";
                    document.getElementById('1').style.display="none";
                   
                    
                }
```

I am then, once the form is submitted, sending my data to a server so that it is emailed to me. The problem is that the previous action, the transition between divs after the button click, is being performed far too quickly. People have told me that it would look a lot better with some sort of transition or a quick loading icon, and that it doesn't look authentic.

Is there any way to have my second div "slide" into the position of the new one? Or some sort of transition? Keep in mind, this is just switching two divs out for one another. No actual data is being processed yet, and no new page is being loaded. Or is there any way to create a loading icon on this action to last for 1second?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Make a full working example of what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try googling "jquery animations" or whatever ui framework you're using (if you're using one). If you're not using a framework for homework or whatever, you'll need to use setTimeout with callbacks to cause intentional delays. It may also be worth researching css transitions (I think that's what they're called), but I haven't worked with them before.

Comment: @AlexMA As another poster suggested, I am using setTimeout. I don't think an animation would be a good idea, so I am going for a loading spinner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// send data
// show loading gif
setTimeout(function () {
     // hide loading gif
     // show other div
}, 2000);
```

You get a 2 second delay this way. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you. Do you have any idea on how to actually make a loading wheel appear? This is a great part 1 of 2 parts to making it perfect!

Comment: Add the loading gif as you would any html element and give it a style display: none. To show the loading gif just do document.getElementById("loadingGifId").style.display = "block". To hide it again document.getElementById("loadingGifId").style.display = "none";

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're open to using jQuery based on your tags. jQuery offers a number of ways to animate changes to divs. `.animate()` provides a way to do custom animations, or your can use one of the provided options. In your case, perhaps something like `.fadeToggle()` would work?

Detailed information here: https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. A problem with those animations is that they don't let the div disappear. I need the div to disappear, maybe fade into total transparency, and then the other one appear.

Comment: @Ryan I think I may misunderstand what you're after, then. From the documentation: "The `.fadeToggle()` method animates the opacity of the matched elements. When called on a visible element, the element's display style property is set to none once the opacity reaches 0, so the element no longer affects the layout of the page."